# Use jQuery variable to show and hide content

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Based on the following HTML:-

```
<div id="content">
     <h1>Main title</h1>
     <h2>Section title</h2>
     <p>Some content...</p>
     <h2>Section title</h2>
     <p>More content...</p>
</div>
```

In jQuery, how would I select and show using variables, only the `<h2>` elements which appear immediately after `<h1>` elements?

I have tried the following, but all elements are still shown:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          var headers =$('h1 + h2');
          headers.show();
     });
</script>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please rephrase your question and provide exactly what's your expected result.

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AEty4/1/

Comment: what are the variables you want to use ?

Comment: which element you want to hide?

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like::

```
$('h1, h2').hide();

$(document).ready(function(){
     var headers =$('h1,h2');
     headers.show();
});
```

And For your Better Reference goto: http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/28mdT/

Answer (score 0):

> show using variables, only the elements which appear immediately after
>   elements?

Your selector [Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) is correct to show the adjacent h1 and h2 but you have to hide the `h1` and `h2` first

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/jfpmB/)**

```
$('h1, h2').hide();

$(document).ready(function(){
     var headers =$('h1 + h2');
     headers.show();
});
```

> **Description:** Selects all next elements matching "next" that are
>   immediately preceded by a sibling "prev", [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/)

Comment: That almost works, but it only displays the first <h2>, note there are two instances of <h1> with <h2> child elements.

Comment: There is only one adjacent h2 to h1, the second h2 is proceeded by p instead of h1

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h1, h2').next().show()
```

Select next sibiling then show them.

Of course if they don't starts hidden they will be everytime visible.

Your code in a `ready()` means that you will show those elements everytime page it's ready, so you'll need to wrap all logic in a conditional statment.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to show it one by one as they appears:

```
$('#content').children().hide(); // hide them first here
$('#content').contents().each(function (index) {
   $(this).delay(index * 300).fadeIn();
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CvCts/)